# DirectAdmin remote MX not working

Tags: exim, directadmin

We're hosting a WordPress website with a Contact Form 7 contactform. 
The e-mails doesn't arrive at the customers e-mail. 
The customer uses Google apps for work so the MX is remote.

Only the domain.com and the www records are pointing to our server. 
In the Exim logs I see this:

2016-02-28 17:04:14 1aa3pO-0005gk-Ty <= username@hostname.com U=username P=local S=824 id=a8eb50f3ba273b9275bb8a2197e63eca@www.domain.com T="Contact form" from  for info@domain.com

2016-02-28 17:04:14 1aa3pO-0005gk-Ty remote host address is the local host: domain.com

2016-02-28 17:04:14 1aa3pO-0005gk-Ty == info@domain.com R=lookuphost defer (-1): remote host address is the local host

2016-02-28 17:04:14 1aa3pO-0005gk-Ty ** info@domain.com: retry timeout exceeded

2016-02-28 17:04:15 1aa3pO-0005gr-VZ => username  F=<> R=localuser T=local_delivery S=1730

2016-02-28 17:04:15 1aa3pO-0005gr-VZ Completed

The local mailserver option in DirectAdmin is off.

I hope someone can help.

Comment: is this real exim log?

Answer (score 0):

Your hosts/DNS point domain.com to local host
If it was example - remove example "domain.com" from Exim local domains
or bad hosts/DNS entry